# Partial Fractions Question: $\frac1{s(n-s)}$

Tags: calculus, fractions

How do you decompose the fraction

> $$\frac1{s(n-s)}
> $$

to two fractions?

($s$ and $n$ are variables).

Comment: Are you Ok with $\frac1{s(n-s)}=\frac1{ns}+\frac1{n(n-s)}$?

Comment: i know that it is the solution but i want to know how and why please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may write, 
$$
\frac1{s(n-s)}=\frac1{n}\frac{n}{s(n-s)}=\frac1{n}\frac{(n-s)+s}{s(n-s)}=\frac1{n}\left(\frac1s+\frac1{n-s} \right)=\frac1{ns}+\frac1{n(n-s)}.
$$

Comment: how do you know that n/n may be multiplied in order to solve this?

Comment: A $n$ was needed in the numerator because I wanted to simplify the factor $(n-s)$ in the denominator, that is $\frac{(n-s)}{s(n-s)}=\frac1s$. Thanks.